# Count of an NSMutable Array of Objects that is in an NSMutable Array of Objects returns 0

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an array of NSObjects (mapArray), and the object being focused on is at position 0 (MAIN_MAP). In each NSObject, there is a NSMutableArray called moonGateArray (has @property and @synthesize) to which I add another NSObject called Moongate. However, I keep getting zero as the count for moonGateArray. Any answers for why that is?

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    [[[mapArray objectAtIndex:MAIN_MAP] moonGateArray] addObject:[Moongate new]];
}
[[[[mapArray objectAtIndex:MAIN_MAP] moonGateArray] objectAtIndex:0] setPosition:9 :3];
[[[[mapArray objectAtIndex:MAIN_MAP] moonGateArray] objectAtIndex:1] setPosition:16 :8];
[[[[mapArray objectAtIndex:MAIN_MAP] moonGateArray] objectAtIndex:2] setPosition:11 :6];
[[[[mapArray objectAtIndex:MAIN_MAP] moonGateArray] objectAtIndex:3] setPosition:16 :13];
[[[[mapArray objectAtIndex:MAIN_MAP] moonGateArray] objectAtIndex:4] setPosition:13 :10];
[[[[mapArray objectAtIndex:MAIN_MAP] moonGateArray] objectAtIndex:5] setPosition:3 :1];
[[[[mapArray objectAtIndex:MAIN_MAP] moonGateArray] objectAtIndex:6] setPosition:3 :12];
[[[[mapArray objectAtIndex:MAIN_MAP] moonGateArray] objectAtIndex:7] setPosition:22 :17];
NSLog(@"%i",[[[mapArray objectAtIndex:MAIN_MAP] moonGateArray] count]);
```

Comment: did you initialized the moonGateArray and mapArray?

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't initialized either mapArray or moonGateArray thats why you are getting 0 count. In objective-c calling count on nil object doest not give any exception but instead returns 0.

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

However for your count=0, this is straight forward you missed to alloc/init any of the array you used.

Are you creating a 2D array or 3D array?

It is creating confusion to get your logic?

Edit:

if your MAIN_APP is always 0, why you need an array, a simple object or instead of storing in 2D array you could have used dictionary. However the entire logic I can guess.

And I would like to add one more thing about your naming conventions... Name suffix or prefix your variable with Array, Button etc. you can use "maps", "moonGates", all plural symbolizes its gonna to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you haven't properly initialize your arrays. Make your like easier and change your code a bit to make it easier to read and easier to debug. You don't get points for writing highly nested method calls. It makes your life harder. Split the code up to make things easier.

Change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    [[[mapArray objectAtIndex:MAIN_MAP] moonGateArray] addObject:[Moongate new]];
}
```

to this:

```
// replace "SomeMapClass" with your actual class name
SomeMapClass *mainMap = mapArray[MAIN_MAP];
NSMutableArray *moonArray = mainMap.moonGateArray;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    [moonArray addObject:[Moongate new]];
}
```

Now you can run this code in the debugger or add NSLog statements and verify each step of the process.

Is `mapArray` properly initialized?
Is `moonArray` property initialized?

Remember, simply defining a property doesn't actually create the object. You still need to initialize it.

Comment: I think my problem is that the moonArray is not initialized. After moonArray = [NSMutableArray new];, the count goes to 8. Is there a way to initialize all the arrays (I have other similar arrays in the Map object) when initializing the object itself?

Comment: Yes, typically this is done in the `init` method (or one of its variants).

Comment: I've looked online for custom initialization, but none of it makes sense. Is it like this: `-(id)initWithVariables {moonGateArray = [NSMutableArray new]; [super init]; }` something like that? And why did my other classes (instance variables are all ints or booleans) not have any problems?

Comment: If it doesn't make sense, you probably need to read a good book. Also, in Xcode's library of code snippets there is a boiler-plate custom initialization method. Generally, you just call your super class's designated initializer and set it to self, make sure self is not nil, do your initialization of state and then return self. Ex. `self = [super initWithImage:image]; if (self) { //stuff here } return self;`